# Mounting Volumes when using Docker module in Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

Here is a snippet from my Ansible playbook ...

My problem is that I can not get the host and container to mount. The specific line is:
**- /home/vagrant/programs/Jenkins:/var/jenkins_home:rw**

If I simply change the line to the below the container starts fine, but there is no mount to the host
**- /home/vagrant/programs/Jenkins**

I am also not sure how I can find any logging to trace is there is a permissions issue or something like that.

Using Ansible 2.2.0.0 and Docker 1.12.3 on Ubuntu Trusty.

```
- name: docker and jenkins
  docker:
    name: jenkins
    image: jenkins
    state:  started
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
   **- /home/vagrant/programs/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home:rw**
```

Thanks

Alistair

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your host permissions. Have you tried executing as root, or using `become` in playbook?

Answer (score -2):

The below code worked for me on python 2.7 docker 18 and ansible 2.7.1

- name: Create a container from the jenkins docker image

  docker_container:

  name: jenkins-ansible

  image: jenkinsci/blueocean

  user: root

  state: started

  recreate: no

  ports:

  ```
  - "8672:8080"

  - "50001:50001"
  ```

  volumes: "/opt/jenkins-ansible:/var/jenkins_home"